# Angular NodeInvocationException: Maximum call stack size exceeded

Tags: asp.net, angular

I have a long html file so I just divide it to some components and then in the app.component.html I insert their selector. 
I just found that if I enter more than 2 selector it shows me the error

```
NodeInvocationException: Maximum call stack size exceeded
RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
```

that's my app.component.html - when I run it show me the error

```
<header></header>
 <navbar></navbar>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
<footer></footer>
```

do you see any error in these files together?

header.component.html -> the header selector

```
<header class="masthead signature-dierk">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
            <article class="col-md-6">
            </article>
            <article class="col-md-6">
            </article>
        </div>
    </div>
</header>
```

**stack trace**

```
    An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.

NodeInvocationException: Maximum call stack size exceeded
RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
at Object.exports.createElement (E:\פרוייקטים\פרוייקטים קיץ\Asp.net\Baber_App\Baber_App\ClientApp\dist\main-server.js:17873:23)
at Parse5DomAdapter.createElement (E:\פרוייקטים\פרוייקטים קיץ\Asp.net\Baber_App\Baber_App\ClientApp\dist\main-server.js:4010:28)
at EmulatedEncapsulationServerRenderer2.DefaultServerRenderer2.createElement (E:\פרוייקטים\פרוייקטים קיץ\Asp.net\Baber_App\Baber_App\ClientApp\dist\main-server.js:4937:51)
at EmulatedEncapsulationServerRenderer2.createElement (E:\פרוייקטים\פרוייקטים קיץ\Asp.net\Baber_App\Baber_App\ClientApp\dist\main-server.js:5157:66)
at BaseAnimationRenderer.createElement (E:\פרוייקטים\פרוייקטים קיץ\Asp.net\Baber_App\Baber_App\ClientApp\dist\main-server.js:15768:30)
at createElement (E:\פרוייקטים\פרוייקטים קיץ\Asp.net\Baber_App\Baber_App\ClientApp\dist\vendor.js:20116:27)
at createViewNodes (E:\פרוייקטים\פרוייקטים קיץ\Asp.net\Baber_App\Baber_App\ClientApp\dist\vendor.js:23093:44)
at callViewAction (E:\פרוייקטים\פרוייקטים קיץ\Asp.net\Baber_App\Baber_App\ClientApp\dist\vendor.js:23573:13)
at execComponentViewsAction (E:\פרוייקטים\פרוייקטים קיץ\Asp.net\Baber_App\Baber_App\ClientApp\dist\vendor.js:23482:13)
at createViewNodes (E:\פרוייקטים\פרוייקטים קיץ\Asp.net\Baber_App\Baber_App\ClientApp\dist\vendor.js:23154:5)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.NodeServices.HostingModels.HttpNodeInstance+<InvokeExportAsync>d__7.MoveNext()
```

Comment: There is nothing in the code you provided that will let us know the answer. At least give the error stack trace.

Comment: I updated my post, you can see please.

Comment: What is `main-server.js` ?

Comment: it's file that create when i open angular 4 project with asp.net

Comment: It's from the build bundle certainly

Comment: yes I guess, looking for any solution, just stuck with that

Comment: Don't you have anything in the components' classes?

Comment: not at all. I just download html template and divide it to selectors for good architecture

Comment: @AdirZoari fyi header is an html5 tag and shouldn't be used as selector for any component. I'm not sure that'd cause any issue though. I'd suggest using dashes in your components. `app-header`. Further more it's confusing for us to read and is bad practice. Further Further more the error doesn't originate from plain html unless you have some circular dependency going on (header in navbar and navbar in header). The error most likely comes from actual js (/ts) code.

Comment: Hey ced! thank you for solving my issue!!! I just waste some hours for that!!!

Comment: @AdirZoari could you tell me what part of my comment solved the issue ?

Comment: I changed header tag to <app-header></app-header>. header is also html5 tag and it also was my selector name.. my mistake

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`header` is an html5 tag and shouldn't be used as selector for any component. I'd suggest using dashes in your components like `app-header`.

Answer (score 0):

the solution is to change the header selector to app-header so it will be

```
<app-header></app-header>
```

Don't forget to change also in header.component.ts in the selector

```
    selector: 'app-header',
```